# Non-fixed length lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match the empty string, preceded either by a vowel and `ck`, or by a vowel and any other consonant (it's from a challenge from CodeGolf). So far I came up with `(?<=[aeiou](?:ck|[^aeiou]))`. The problem with this is that it just won't match after `ck` with `[^aeiou]` there. It always matches after a `c` in the case of, say, `nickel` : `nic-kel`. Why does this happen?

Comment: A consonant can be defined as `[a-zA-Z-[aeiou]]`.

Comment: I bet you need `(?<=[aeiou](?:(?!ck)[a-zA-Z-[aeiou]]|ck))`. Lookbehind is a nonconsuming pattern that - being unanchored - is tried at each location in the string. Since you allow matching the location preceded with a vowel and any char but a vowel you will get the matches between `c` and `k` and `k` and `e`.

Comment: Fwiw, posted a simple solution `(?<=[aeiou](?:ck|(?!ck)[^aeiou]))` and the reason why it was doing that. If the requirement isn't so strict on what a consonant is, you could just use `[^aeiou]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
(?<=[aeiou](?:(?!ck)[a-zA-Z-[aeiou]]|ck))
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5baeiou%5d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!ck%29%5ba-zA-Z-%5baeiou%5d%5d%7cck%29%29.&i=nickel).

Lookbehind is a nonconsuming pattern that - being unanchored - is tried at each location in the string. Since you allow matching the location preceded with a vowel and any char but a vowel you will get the matches between `c` and `k` and `k` and `e`.

If you want to allow matching the position after a vowel followed with any consonant but not when there is a `ck` clustet temper the consonant pattern with a `(?!ck)` negative lookahead, `(?!ck)`. The consonant must be matched with `[a-zA-Z-[aeiouAEIOU]]`. That matches any ASCII letter but `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` (case insensitively).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your regex, just need to add a simple `(?!ck)`
before the consonants.

`(?<=([aeiou](?:ck|(?!ck)[^aeiou])))`

```
 (?<=
      (                     # (1 start)
           [aeiou] 
           (?:
                ck
             |  (?! ck )    # <== here
                [^aeiou] 
           )
      )                     # (1 end)
 )
```

But, you may want to know the reason why.

The reason is that on *variable length* lookbehinds in C#
it starts at a point between a character.

*At any point, and only that point it looks backwards for a match*.
All that is *ahead* of it is not allowed in the match.

Let's see how they do it :

---

Using your regex `(?<=[aeiou](?:ck|[^aeiou]))`

`i`<=absolute position `ck` , then looks back

Finds `[aeiou]`.

Fails `ck` and `[^aeiou]`

Goes forward (to right) by 1 position, then looks back

`ic`<=absolute position `k`

Fails `ck`

BUT, matches the 'c' with `[^aeiou]`

---

The important thing to remember is that it can't defy it's own
two *primary* rules.

Their rules state that it has to take the first match it finds,
and it must find it looking backwards between characters.

So, it's clear that if finds and matches this `ic`<=absolute position `k`
first.

Each assertion is in it's own relative frame position that is
independent of it's surrounding code.
That position is dynamic (changing) and it's origin is the current position
of the calling expression (even another assertion).

So when calling an assertion *inside* assertion it just takes the parents  current position and does it's checking from that position, internally
maintaining it's *own* current position.

---

Lets see what the *fix* does `(?<=[aeiou](?:ck|(?!ck)[^aeiou]))`

`i`<=absolute position `ck` , then looks back

Finds `[aeiou]`.

Fails `ck` and `[^aeiou]`

Goes forward (to right) by 1 position, then looks back

`ic`<=absolute position `k`

Note that internally, it is matching forward and the
relative position is now here =>`ck`
because it already matched the `i` and is checking after it.

Fails `ck` because the 'k' would extend 1 character beyond its
absolute position

HOWEVER, it could match 'c' with `[^aeiou]` without going beyond it's absolute position

To *STOP* that, just a simple `(?!ck)` is needed before `[^aeiou]`

At this point `(?!ck)` is passed this relative position, and it
is not restricted by the callers absolute position.

It see's there is a `ck` looking forward and returns a false condition
making the outer assertion fail.

Goes forward (to right) by 1 position, then looks back

`ick`<=absolute position , then looks back

This time it scores a match on the `ick`

---

**Demo**

Target string

```
nickel : nic-ikel
```

C#

```
string Stxt = "nickel : nic-ikel";
var RxR = new Regex(@"(?<=([aeiou](?:ck|(?!ck)[^aeiou])))");

foreach (Match match in RxR.Matches(Stxt))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output

```
ick
el
ic
ik
el
```